# API Testing, "message": "{'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}"

Tags: java, api

```java
public void SetThePlan(Map<String, String> testData, long numbers, String timeStamp) 
{
    String payLoad = this.gson.toJson(new BillingPOJO().setPlan(testData, numbers, timeStamp));
    Response response = this.restUtils.post(payLoad,testData.get("api_url"));

    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
    Assert.assertEquals(statusCode,200);

    String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
    System.out.println(responseBody);
}
```

This is the code I'm using to setThePlan on api.

But, after recieving the response, the status code is 200, but it is not showing the appropriate response body.  Instead, it is showing this response body.

```json
{
    "status": "failed",
    "message": "{'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}"
}
```

I've checked every payload values, it is ok.  It is hitting the api and getting the success message on the postman when done manually.  but it is not happening on the intelliJ.  why?

I've tried, computed diff to check whether the postman payload and the actual payload of my automation is similar.  yes it is simialr.

Comment: You tag your question with #restassured but you do not have any restassured code in your example. Only some custom `restUtils` which can also have issues with implementation. Also why you convert your object to `String`? you can post POJOs with RA straight away.